# How to change an angular 2 library to make it available for ES5?

Tags: angular

I'm not an Angular2 master, and I'm working in ES5 mode. Everything is OK, except when I want to use a new library. Some of them don't provide their libraries for ES5, the way you use ng.core and ng.common etc.

I Googled around and couldn't find an answer to this question:

When finding an Angular 2 library which contains a bunch of directives and providers and modules probably and other things, how can we change it to make it available in ES5?

Comment: You can use javascript compiler [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/repl/) to do so.